# How to build user interface to my (winforms) in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ui-design

I need to change my Application forms to flat design

How can I make a design that I can use it in all of my projects by drag an drop
from the toolbox?
(Like CSS in HTML)

Comment: Create custom controls? `Project -> Add -> Custom Control`. Once you've added a custom control, rebuild your project and they'll appear in your toolbox.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Styles` and `ControlTemplates` in **WPF** will allow you to override the look and feel of any element, be it a `Button` or a `TextBox`.

Comment: WPF or WinForm? Can't be both.